# Make boolean values editable in list_display?

Tags: django, django-admin

I'd like a boolean field to be editable in my Django admin's list display. Instead, I have uneditable icons:

[image]

My code looks like this:

```
# Model
class Task(models.Model):
  ...
  is_finished = models.BooleanField() 
# Admin
list_display = (..., 'is_finished')
```

I haven't included `is_finished` in the `readonly_fields` tuple in `admin.py`, so I'm surprised that it isn't editable by default. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you put `is_finished` in `list_editable`?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

`ModelAdmin.list_editable` is what you need, see its doc [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/). Below you also have an example:

```
class TaskAdmin(models.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (..., 'is_finished')
    list_editable = ('is_finished',) # this MUST only contain fields that also are in "list_display"
    #list_display_links = ('foo', 'bar') # this MUST NOT contain a field in common with "list_editable"
```

Comment: where should I pin the action which should be executed when state changed? save_model in django admin?

Comment: `list_editable` also creates a `Save` button at the bottom of the list_view searched for it almost half an hour.