# How to add a custom boolean action button in Django Admin?

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a model which is registered with the admin.

```
models.py
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    is_enabled = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Now, I want that the admin can only enable or disable the Post by interacting with is_enabled field of the model.

```
admin.py
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['id', 'title', 'tag', 'is_enabled']
    list_display_links = None
    readonly_fields = ['id', 'title', 'tag']

    actions = ['enable_selected', 'disable_selected']

    def enable_selected(self,requst,queryset):
        queryset.update(is_enabled=True)

    def disable_selected(self,requst,queryset):
        queryset.update(is_enabled=False)

    enable_selected.short_description = "Enable the selected Post"
    disable_selected.short_description = "Disable the selected Post"
```

I have successfully added these actions on the dropdown, however I need to add this in the form of a button on the list, also I need to know how can I call a function when the button is hit to update the is_enabled field.

Comment: Do you want it for Each separately right in listing?

Comment: yes, I want then on each row. Example.
|id| |title| |tag| |is_enabled| |action|
The action colum should consist of button to enable or disable the post on that particular row.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make boolean values editable in list\_display?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18107589/make-boolean-values-editable-in-list-display)

Answer (score 2):

You can use **list_editable**

```
list_editable = ['is_enabled']
```

Remember to add **is_enabled** in list_display (ModelAdmin)also

Comment: It's already there if you see, I'm showing the boolean fields in the form of icons.

Comment: @Paras After you edit the is_enabled in listing you can save them using the save button below